# Random ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx

I have a rather large JavaFX Application which works well most of the time.
However, sometimes I get random ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions when clicking through the application. I can't reproduce the errors and don't know when they appear: Sometimes I can click through the application without any problems, and sometimes the app crashes and the stacktrace appears.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1591)
at javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1535)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_computeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1388)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.impl_computeGeomBounds(Region.java:3078)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3641)
at javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3424)
at javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:559)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1719)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1717)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When reading the stacktrace, the only thing which caught my attention is that the error doesn't even happen in some of my code.
Does anyone of you know problems like this and has an idea, where I could start investigating or what could be causing this problem?

I tried it on JDK 1.8.0_74 (Windows 8.1 x64), JDK 1.8.0_77 (Windows 8.1 x64) and JDK 1.8.0_91 (OS X 10.11)

Comment: Do you update the ui from a thread other than the application thread. There were a few similar issues in the last few days that were related to updating the UI from the wrong thread.

Comment: You have an equivalent stacktrace here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769896/unexpected-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-javafx-application-refering-to-no maybe it can help figuring out what's wrong

Comment: Maybe an exception break point would help, you could hop through each frame in the stack and analyze variables and fields to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Fabian was right, I made UI changes from a thread other than the ui thread. For the moment I fixed it with "Platform.runLater" but I'll refactor my architecture. Strange thing is that I though UI changes from outside threads would always fail, and not just sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm pretty new at JavaFX, I might be wrong but I faced this exact same problem while writing a game. The problem in my case was that I was trying to move the objects from a different thread than the "JavaFX Application Thread". As you haven't provided your code, I cant be sure but I would suggest you to make any changes to the GUI only through the "JavaFX Application Thread" and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to look out for all the array declarations and then checking if any one of them is accessesed dynamically, in such a way that it may cause the index to go out of bounds.

If you can introduce logging into the your application, you can introduce debug `logs (log.debug(myArray.size() + arrayAccessVariable) )`

Check if any of the arrays is being initialized by inputs from the GUI (a common source of error).

I think in your case, it being accessed by a -1. A good practice is to introduce negative checks, just before each access.

Another good idea would be to use `ArrayList` or any other datatype, that can resize itself when needed.